# Yii2 Yii::$app->user->getId(); ignores number '0' at the end of an integer

Tags: yii, yii2

My question is pretty straight-forward. I tried to get StudentId that was stored inside Yii::$app->user->getId(), but for some reasons it ignores the value '0' at the end of it. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? Have been searching for hours and seems like noone has ever faced it.

Summary: Yii2 seems to ignore the value '0' at the end of an integer.

```
Yii::$app->user->getId();
```

The above returns StudentId as 183 instead of the correct one 18300.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fetch the id from the student table? If yes and assuming that your student record has a relationship with the user record, then to get the student id:

```
$student_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->student->id;
```

The *user* in the code is of the yii\web\User, while the *identity* is usually your active record.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have no problem to fetch the StudentId. The problem is I fetched the StudentId which is 18300 but Yii2 displays as 183. It ignored the two 0 values at the of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is solved. Just noticed the StudentId I was supposed to get is 18100 and Yii2 displays 183 instead. I just restarted xampp and it now shows 18100. I'm not sure why and I have no idea at all. But it is fixed now.